# How can I get a list of the affected files in the webhook using GitLab?

Tags: ruby, git, gitlab

I want to incorporate some functionality to the file that the web hook hits, and part of that is needing to know the file names of the files that were added/modified/deleted in the last commit.

Bit Bucket's hook API sends this information, but GitLab doesn't. Is it possible to add this as a custom hook? Perhaps there is another way of obtaining the list of files?